# Unable to query on Partition key in DyanmoDB by boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have one table `TestTable` and partition Key `TestColumn`.

Inputs Dates:

```
from_date= "2017-04-20T16:31:54.451071+00:00"
to_date = "2018-04-20T16:31:54.451071+00:00"
```

when I use equal query the date then it is working.

```
key_expr = Key('TestColumn').eq(to_date)
query_resp = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=key_expr)
```

but when I use `between` query then is not working.

```
key_expr = Key('TestColumn').between(from_date, to_date)
query_resp = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=key_expr)
```

Error:
`Unknown err_msg while querying dynamodb: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DynamoDb "Query key condition not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414535/dynamodb-query-key-condition-not-supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

DynamoDB Query will return data from one and only one partition, meaning you have to supply a single partition key in the request.

> **KeyConditionExpression**
>
> The condition that specifies the key value(s)
>   for items to be retrieved by the Query action.
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
>   value.

You can optionally use a BETWEEN operator on a sort key (but you still have to supply a single partition key).

If you use a `Scan` you can use an `ExpressionFilter` and use the BETWEEN operator on `TestColumn`