# How can I query dynamodb to return items where a numeric secondary key is smaller than a supplied value?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table called posts. It has a secondary index 'tsProcess' that is a number.

In a lambda function I want to query for all items where tsProcess is less than a value, in the example below I am trying to find all items where tsProcess is less than 1600.

Here is the code:

```
ex = {
    TableName: "posts",
    IndexName: "tsProcess-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "tsProcess < :t1",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":t1": 1600,
    },
};
command = new QueryCommand(ex);
```

This gets the response:

```
"errorType": "ValidationException",
"errorMessage": "Query key condition not supported",
```

Is it possible to run a query in this way? How do I need to change the expression to accomplish it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DynamoDb "Query key condition not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414535/dynamodb-query-key-condition-not-supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Query, you must also provide the partition key value.

```
KeyConditionExpression: "myPk= 1 AND tsProcess < :t1"
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

If the partition key is unknown, you will have to use `Scan` with a Filter expression, which reads every item in the table.

---

If your index has a partition key of `tsProcess` then you must provide the equality `=` operator on it, you cannot do a range condition on a partition key, only on the sort key.

Comment: Why is it required to also provide the partition key value? I though that a secondary index effectively creates a copy of the table, with the index as its primary key (partition key)?

Comment: Ok, so your index has a key which is `tsProcess`? In that case you must provide a full equality operator, you cannot do a condition on the partition key, only the sort key.